# C++ - Still getting local ip instead of clients

Tags: c++, sockets, ip, client, local

I've a problem on getting the clients ip address using sockets.
I still get '127.0.0.1' as the client-ip. But why? Wheres the problem?

Here's a snippet of the serializement (first step):

```
int Serializement::serialize(std::string srvip, unsigned short portno)
{
wsaError = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
if (wsaError != 0)
{
    printf("Server: The Winsock dynamic link library (dll) was not found!\n");
    retval = 100;
    return 100;
}
else 
    if (ConfigLoaderH::ConfigLoader::ServerDisplayMessages() != 0)
    {
        printf("Server: The Windsock dll was found!\n");
        printf("Server: The status: %s.\n", wsaData.szSystemStatus);
    }

if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
{
    printf("Server: The dll does not support the Winsock version %u.%u!\n", LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion), HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion));
    WSACleanup();
    retval = 101;
    return 101;
}
else
    if (ConfigLoaderH::ConfigLoader::ServerDisplayMessages() != 0)
    {
        printf("Server: The dll supports the Winsock version %u.%u!\n", LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion), HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion));
        printf("Server: The hightest version this dll can support: %u.%u!\n", LOBYTE(wsaData.wHighVersion), HIBYTE(wsaData.wHighVersion));
    }


m_Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (m_Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Server: Error at socket(): %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    retval = 102;
    return 102;
}
else
    if (ConfigLoaderH::ConfigLoader::ServerDisplayMessages() != 0)
        printf("Server: socket() is OK!\n");


service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(srvip.c_str());
service.sin_port = htons(portno);

int yes = 1;

if (setsockopt(m_Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&yes, sizeof(yes)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    if (ConfigLoaderH::ConfigLoader::ServerDisplayMessages() != 0)
        printf("Server: Reuse Address was successful.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Server: Reusing address failed...\n");
    retval = 103;
    return 103;
}
if (bind(m_Socket, (sockaddr *)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Server: bind() failed, %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(m_Socket);
    retval = 104;
    return 104;
}
else
    if (ConfigLoaderH::ConfigLoader::ServerDisplayMessages() != 0)
        printf("Server: bind() is OK!\n");

if (listen(m_Socket, 10) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Server: listen(): Error listening on socket %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
    retval = 105;
    return 105;
}
else
    printf("***Hint: Server is ready... Application form can now be run...***\n");

retval = 106;
return 106; }
```

And here's a snippet of the listening (second step):

```
...sockaddr_in client_info;...
... try
    {
        printf("Server: Waiting for a client to connect...\n");
        client_info = { 0 };
        socklen_t c_len = sizeof(client_info);

        AcceptSocket = accept(m_Socket, (sockaddr *)&client_info, &c_len);
        if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            printf("Server: accept() failed.\n");
        else
        {
            char * connected_ip = inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr);
            printf("Connected client-ip: %s\n", connected_ip);
        }

        printf("Server: Getting client-info is done!\n");
```

I hope someone will find the line/s that causes that mistake.
Thank you in future!

Comment: Just ruling out the obvious: you're not running both processes on the same machine?

Comment: It's one application, running on the same machine.

Comment: If you run them on the same machine, why are you expecting that machine to have different addresses?

Comment: Don't understand me wrong. The server is running on the machine and works with a PHP-script. Over the php script there gets data sent by a socket connection.

Comment: I'm trying to get the ip-adress of the client that triggers the button on web to send data to the server

Comment: If you have two processes,  PHP and C++, communicating over a socket,  and they're both running on the same machine, they have the same IP. The web server's client is not your C++ server's client.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code shown (although your error handling could be better).  If `accept()` succeeds, it returns the correct client IP and port, as it is known to the server socket. If that is being reported as 127.0.0.1 then it means the client is not only running on the same machine as the server socket, but also that the client used 127.0.0.1 to `connect()` to the server port. There is no other way that 127.0.0.1 could be getting reported given the code shown.